# Referencing programmatically made objects in other methods

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, object

I have made this ImageView (`UIImageView`) programmatically in the `viewDidLoad` method.

```
  UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 200, 100, 100)];
  imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageviewImage.png"];
  [self.view addSubview:imageview];
```

But when I create the button like this in the `viewDidLoad` method I can't reference it in other methods in the same class. Let's say I want to change the ImageView alpha to 0.0f in an `IBAction` method in the same class. I can' just reference to imageview like this:

```
  -(IBAction) button {
  imageview.alpha = 0.0f;
  }
```

What is the easiest thing to do with the ImageView if I want to reference it in another method?

PS: The ImageView has to be made programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is scope.  The imageView pointer you create in viewDidLoad is only accessible there.  Either create a property or use a tag.

1) Create a property:

```
// top of the .m file
@interface MyClass () /* replace MyClass with your class name */
@property(strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
@end

// in viewDidLoad, don't declare UIImageView *imageView, just replace
// all mentions of it with self.imageView;
```

2) Or use a tag:

```
// top of the .m file
#define kIMAGE_VIEW_TAG   128

// in viewDidLoad
UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(110, 200, 100, 100)];
imageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageviewImage.png"];
imageView.tag = kIMAGE_VIEW_TAG;
[self.view addSubview:imageview];

// elsewhere in the code, when you want the image view
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:kIMAGE_VIEW_TAG];
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you're declaring it locally. Make it an instance variable of your class instead.

```
@interface MyClass: NSObject {
    UIImageView *imageView;
}

- (void)foo
{
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
}

- (void)bar
{
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"baz"];
}
```